# Not able to install "DateTime" package in Julia 1.0?

Tags: julia

Not able to add "DateTime" package in Julia 1.0. How to sort this issue ??; 
using Pkg

```
julia> Pkg.add("DateTime")
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * dateTime (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/Types.jl:120
 [2] #ensure_resolved#72(::Bool, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/Types.jl:1010
 [3] #ensure_resolved at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [4] #add_or_develop#15(::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/API.jl:49
 [5] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [6] #add_or_develop#14 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/API.jl:31 [inlined]
 [7] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [8] #add_or_develop#13 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/API.jl:29 [inlined]
 [9] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [10] #add_or_develop#12(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,Symbol,Tuple{Symbol},NamedTuple{(:mode,),Tuple{Symbol}}}, ::Function, ::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/API.jl:28
 [11] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [12] #add#20 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/API.jl:59 [inlined]
 [13] add(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/Pkg/src/API.jl:59
 [14] top-level scope at none:0

julia>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of `DateTime.jl` reads:

> This project is now obsolete. Starting with version 0.4-dev, date and
>   time functionality has been added to Julia base.

What is the functionality that you need? Normally, when working with date use the in-built `Dates` package

```
using Dates
```

#### EDIT

Since you have asked for an example here it is:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> d = DataFrame( col1 = ["2018-01-01","2018-02-10","2018-03-20"])
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ col1       │
│     │ String     │
├─────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 2018-01-01 │
│ 2   │ 2018-02-10 │
│ 3   │ 2018-03-20 │

julia> using Dates

julia> d.col1 = Date.(d.col1);

julia> d
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ col1       │
│     │ Date       │
├─────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 2018-01-01 │
│ 2   │ 2018-02-10 │
│ 3   │ 2018-03-20 │
```

Note how the dot operator `.` has been used to vectorize the operation.

Comment: Thanks,
The dataset, I'm using have more than 100 rows and 100 columns.How do, I change only datetime format for the entire column in one go ?

Comment: Here you go - I extended the answer.